# In Angular, how do I avoid a "Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'" error?

Tags: json, angular, rest

I'm using Angular 7 and trying to read JSON data from a Rails 5 app.  I have this in my src/app/app.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  books;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    http.get('http://localhost:3000/books.json')
      .subscribe(res => this.books = res.json());
  }
}
```

However, when i start up my Angular app using "ng serve," I get this error

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(15,42): error TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

I have confirmed that when I visit hte endpoint, http://localhost:3000/books.json, I get the output

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Copying and Pasting from Stack Overflow","created_at":"2019-08-14T19:55:57.961Z","updated_at":"2019-08-14T19:55:57.961Z"},{"id":2,"name":"Trying Stuff Until it Works","created_at":"2019-08-14T19:55:57.966Z","updated_at":"2019-08-14T19:55:57.966Z"}]
```

so I'm confused about what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data) by default extracts the JSON for you behind the scenes without needing to use `json()`. `HttpModule` in Angular 2.x required you to extract using `json()`, but `HttpClient` of 4.x+ does this for you. You can simply directly access the parsed JSON data in `subscribe()`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  books;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    http.get('http://localhost:3000/books.json')
      .subscribe(res => this.books = res);
  }
}
```

It is really recommend you take advantage of TypeScript and [type-check the response](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response):

```
interface Book {
  someProperty: string;
  anotherProperty: number;
}

// ...

books: Book[];

// ...

http.get<Book[]>('http://localhost:3000/books.json')
  .subscribe(res => this.books = res);
```

Hopefully that helps!