# How to execute javascript code on angular2+ html template

Tags: javascript, angular

How to execute javascript code like `JSON.parse()` in the angular html template itself instead of making a method and calling the method in the angular html template file

I tried below ways:

`<p [innerHTML]="JSON.parse(['\\u2013'])[0]"></p>`

`<p>{{ JSON.parse(['\\u2013'])[0] }}</p>`

But getting **Property 'JSON' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.**

Can it be possible to write javascript code on angular html template itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Angular, how do I avoid a "Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57502198/in-angular-how-do-i-avoid-a-property-json-does-not-exist-on-type-object-e)

Comment: No @ethry that doesn't answer my question. I am asking about execute javascript code on html template not about response.json() of http calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you write in .html should be a "public" (variable or object or function). So, we can **not** use, e.g. `{{Math.random()}}` nor `{{JSON.parse('["\\u2013"]')[0]}}` or `{{Array.from('foo')}}`

See the quotes in JSON.parse

Well, you always can assign a public variable in your .ts (by defect all the variables are public) to the javascript object you want

```
//declare in your .ts (I choose give the same "name" to the variable)
JSON:any=JSON
Math:any=Math
Array:any=Array
```

And use in .html

```
<div>
   {{Math.random()*10}}
   {{JSON.parse('["\\u2013"]')[0]}}
</div>
<div *ngFor="let a of Array.from('foo')">Hello</div>
```

BTW, if you want to execute javascript, I suggest executed in ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit functions

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code inside a function in you component.ts file and then call  that function from html file.

**component.ts**

```
parseJson(data) {
  return JSON.parse(data);
}
```

**component.html**

```
<p>{{parseJson(['\\u2013'])[0]}}</p>
```

Comment: OP does not want to make a method.

Comment: Yeah I know this one. But I don't want to call a method from typescript file. Please read the question again

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part.